# makefile place the generated obj into particular folder

Tags: gcc, makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to reorganize my project to put all generated object file in a particular "obj" folder, when I just handle c files I used below makefile and it works fine(I put src1.c in src1 dir,src2.c in src2 dir and src3.c in src3 dir).

```
vpath %.c src
vpath %.c src2 
vpath %.c src3

D_OBJ = obj
CC = gcc

SRC_C   = src1.c src2.c src3.c
OBJ_C   = $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC_C))))
DEP  = $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/, $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(notdir $(SRC_C))))

.PHONY: all 

all:$(OBJ_C) 

$(D_OBJ)/%.o:%.c 
    $(CC) -c -Wall  $< -o $@ -MMD -MF $(D_OBJ)\\$*.d -MP 


-include $(DEP)
```

currently, I have asm and S files in src1,src2 and src3 called file1.asm file2.asm file3.asm and sfile1.s,sfile2.s and sfile3.s. 
how can I put all of these files generated .o into obj folder?

I tried below but doesn't work

```
vpath %.c src
vpath %.c src2 
vpath %.c src3
vpath %.s src
vpath %.s src2 
vpath %.s src3 
vpath %.asm src
vpath %.asm src2 
vpath %.asm src3 

D_OBJ = obj
CC = gcc

SRC_C   = src1.c src2.c src3.c
SRC_ASM = file1.asm file2.asm file3.asm
SRC_S = sfile1.s sfile2.s sfile3.s
OBJ_C   = $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/,$(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC_C))))
OBJ_S   = $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/,$(patsubst %.s,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC_S))))
OBJ_ASM   = $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/,$(patsubst %.asm,%.o,$(notdir $(SRC_ASM))))
DEP  = $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/, $(patsubst %.c,%.d,$(notdir $(SRC_C))))
DEP += $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/, $(patsubst %.s,%.d,$(notdir $(SRC_S))))
DEP += $(addprefix $(D_OBJ)/, $(patsubst %.asm,%.d,$(notdir $(SRC_ASM))))

.PHONY: all 

all:$(OBJ_C) $(OBJ_ASM) $(OBJ_S)

$(D_OBJ)/%.o:%.c 
    $(CC) -c -Wall  $< -o $@ -MMD -MF $(D_OBJ)\\$*.d -MP 

$(D_OBJ)/%.o:%.asm 
    $(CC) -c -Wall  $< -o $@ -MMD -MF $(D_OBJ)\\$*.d -MP 

$(D_OBJ)/%.o:%.s 
    $(CC) -c -Wall  $< -o $@ -MMD -MF $(D_OBJ)\\$*.d -MP 

-include $(DEP)
```

got error :make: *** No rule to make target `obj/file1.o', needed by`all'.  Stop.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you have another problem, because I just tried your Makefile with the same folder structure and files, replacing the compiler calls by `echo $< built to $@`, and it works perfectly. Maybe double check you've not done a typo somewhere ?

Comment: Why are you writing `$(D_OBJ)\\$*.d` instead of `$(D_OBJ)/%*.d`?  That doesn't look right.

Comment: @MadScientist Thanks for your reply, I am using window not linux so I changed to \\

Comment: @Tim Hi, Thank you for your reply. which part of makefile works? just C files or C ,S and ASM files?

Comment: All of it. I literally copy pasted the whole make file and just replaced the build command by an écho outputting the files names. And I created the matching folder structure with all types of files. It all works well.

Comment: You should use forward-slashes not backslashes, even on Windows, when writing makefiles.  And certainly when invoking software that was migrated from POSIX systems such as GNU/Linux, over to Windows.  I don't know if that will solve your problem but you shouldn't be using backslashes in makefiles, unless you're running old DOS/Windows command.com commands like `rmdir` etc. which require them.

Comment: @Tim Thank you so much, I found the issue , the file name is wrong in my src folder. Yes, the makefile works :)

Comment: @MadScientist I changed the backslash to slash, I found both backslash and slash work in my window10 environment. I will keep the slash in future. Thanks.